# Rigged mesh doesn't animate (despite the bones moving)

Tags: animation, three.js

I have a model with a skeleton, all set up.

I've added the animations and Animation Helper to see the model move.
The result is odd - the bones are moving (according to animation helper rendering), but the actual model itself does not.

It's better explained with an gif:

[image: problem]

Animation is attached to the mesh using:

animation = new THREE.Animation( mesh, geometry.animation );

Any suggestions on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was pretty simple actually:

```
                for ( var k in materials ) {
                    materials[k].skinning = true;
                }
```